# Is there a more efficient way of getting the type of derived class when working with a pointer to an abstract base class?

Tags: c++

I have six different classes that are all derived from an abstract base class named "Piece".

When looping through a vector of pointers to Piece as such:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<Piece>>
```

Is there an efficient way to get the type of derived class that each pointer is pointing to?

Obviously I can just do something like this:

```
class Piece
{
public:
    virtual std::string getType() = 0;
}

class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    std::string getType() override
    {
        return "Rook";
    }
}
class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    std::string getType() override
    {
        return "Pawn";
    }
}


for (std::shared_ptr<Piece> p: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>>)
{
    if (p->getType() == "Rook")
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else if(p->getType() == "Pawn")
    {
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

But it seems like there would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Normally you would instead add a `virtual` member function to `Piece` and override that member function in each derived type with whatever `//Do something` and `//Do something else` are in their respective implementation.

Comment: Why would you do that? The `for` loop written this way is not OOP but procedural code disguised as OOP. Move the _"Do something"_ and _"Do something else"_ into the respective classes, into a virtual method.

Comment: @axiac We've already covered that solution nicely, and in the proper place to boot. We don't need the angry version in comments any more. :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Who's angry?

Comment: @axiac You seem to be!

Comment: If you need a discriminated union, write a discriminated union (std::variant etc). Don't try to shove the OOP paradigm where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Note that needing to get the type of derived class usually means you need to step back and redesign the interface

Answer (score 6):

Slightly more efficient would be an `enum` rather than a string, as these can be compared slightly faster (they're one integer!).

But it's ideal to try to avoid this need, if you can.

This:

```
if (p->getType() == "Rook")
{
    //Do something
}
else if(p->getType() == "Pawn")
{
    //Do something else
}
```

should just be this:

```
p->doThing();
```

… where `doThing` is a `virtual` function that does "the right thing" for whatever class it's implemented in.

Failing that, your pattern is not unusual.

Comment: @NathanOliver Now we just need a language that doesn't require any explicit implementation for such a function :D

Comment: Sounds like one of the items on my Wishlist: Telepathic compiler that generates executable code that does what I want it to do, not what I told it to do.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Maybe I should have been a bit more clear about what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to display pieces of the same type together (when they are defeated), so first the pawns, then the knights etc. So basically sorting a vector by the piece types. Should I go with the enum solution then, or could I solve it by adding another virtual member function to Piece?

Answer (score 1):

As another answer shows, using an enum would be more efficient than using a string.  But at the cost of having to maintain that enum if you ever decide to add more `Piece`-derived classes in the future (though, Chess only has a few distinct pieces, so I'm sure that will not happen).

Otherwise, have a look at [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) or [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) instead of a `virtual` method, eg:

```cpp
class Piece
{
public:
    virtual ~Piece() = default;
    ...
};

class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    ...
    void doSomething();
};

class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    ...
    void doSomethingElse();
};

...

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>> pieces;
...
for (auto p : pieces)
{
    if (Rook *rk = dynamic_cast<Rook*>(p.get()))
    // or: if (auto rk = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Rook>(p))
    {
        rk->doSomething();
    }
    if (Pawn *pn = dynamic_cast<Pawn*>(p.get()))
    // or: if (auto pn = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Pawn>(p))
    {
        pn->doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

But, as others have stated, this is not a good class design.  This would be better handled by using a single `virtual` method for the actual work instead, eg:

```cpp
class Piece
{
public:
    virtual ~Piece() = default;
    virtual void someAction() = 0;
    ...
};

class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    ...
    void someAction() override {
        // do something ...
    }
};

class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    ...
    void someAction() override {
        // do something else ...
    }
};

...

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>> pieces;
...
for (auto p : pieces)
{
    p->someAction();
}
```

Comment: fwiw, I recently saw `;;;` as placeholder for missing code. It has the nice advantage over `...` that it is valid almost anywhere and it cannot be confused with pack expansion (not a problem here)

Comment: I would argue that `dynamic_cast` is the wrong direction. If virtual dispatch doesn't suit your use case for whatever reason, why pay the cost of RTTI? Granted, you're saving the "overhead" of managing and comparing the enums, but...

Comment: Good spot on the virtual destructor, though, and this probably ought to be called out more explicitly.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I would argue that placeholder text being valid code "almost anywhere" is a bad thing, not a good thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using enums and a function in base.

Untested concept code

```cpp
enum class PieceType { Rock, Pawn, etc. };
class Piece {
  enum id = -1; // no such piece
public:
    virtual std::string getType() = 0;
    enum PieceType GetId() {
      return id;
    }
}

class Rook : public Piece {
public:
    Rock() : id(PieceType::Rock) {}
    std::string getType() override  {
        return "Rook";
    }
}
```

If it needs to be fast then this would do, if you just need to display it for one player once in a while, your method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "Rook" and "Pawn" don't know about each other (like they are of different libraries) and that they also know nothing about your "Do something" code nor you have a vector of std::variant, it's not an easy task as you need to use some double-dispatch method.

The common solution is to create visitor interface per each derived class and visitor accept method.
So you have your Piece.cpp file:

```
struct Piece;
struct IPieceVisitor { 
    virtual void visit(Piece*) = 0;
};
struct Piece {
    virtual void accept(IPieceVisitor *v) { 
        v->visit(this);
    }
};
```

And Rook.cpp with all others implementing classes should have:

```
struct Rook;
struct IRookVisitor: public virtual IPieceVisitor {
    virtual void visit(Rook*) = 0;
};
struct Rook : public Piece { 
     void accept(IPieceVisitor *v) override {
         if(IRookVisitor *rv = dynamic_cast<IRookVisitor*>(v) {
             return rv->visit(this);
         }
         Piece::accept(v); // consider that it may also be derived from some SpecialPiece
    }   
};
```

Now you can write your "Do something" visitor:

```
struct GratherKnownPiecesVisitor:
    public IRookVisitor, public IPawnVisitor {
 
    void visit(Rook* r) override{
        m_knownPieces.push_back(r);
    }
    void visit(Pawn* p) override {
        m_knownPieces.push_back(p);
    }
    void visit(Piece* p) override {
        std::cerr << "Unknown piece!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<std::variant<Rook*,Pawn*>> m_knownPieces;
};
```

Now you can smoothly run over the unknown container of base class pointers:

```
GratherKnownPiecesVisitor knownTypesVisitor;
for (std::shared_ptr<Piece> p: pieces) {
    p->accept(&knownTypesVisitor);
}
```

The easier and perhaps faster solution is to use hash map indexed with type information:
`std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::functinon<void(Piece*)>>`

But that way if someone create SpecialRook class, we cannot know that it is derived from our Rook class.

The fastest solution is to assign each object a value of your enum and then switch case to the type you want.